# NullPointerException when trying to run code generated by wsdl2java

Tags: jax-ws, cxf

I am trying to build a WS client using Apache CXF 2.7.11. I created the sample classes using `wsdl2java` tool. I have a Eclipse project with:

- all the code generated by wsdl2java
- all the jar files from /lib installed.

I am basically following this tutorial: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-consumer.html

When I run the sample code created by `wsdl2java`, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:98)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:204)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:149)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:101)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:67)
at com.twinfield.Session.<init>(Session.java:46)
at com.twinfield.SessionSoap_SessionSoap_Client.main(SessionSoap_SessionSoap_Client.java:48)
```

Using the debugger, I found out that the null in question is caused by `CXFBusImpl.getExtension(WSDLManager.class)`. Line 98 in WSDLServiceFactory.java reads:

```
definition = getBus().getExtension(WSDLManager.class).getDefinition(url);
```

I thought that the problem was with my wsdl location, but based on above that might not be the case? I have tried both local file and an URL as a value to the -wsdlLocation switch of `wsdl2java`. (Currently I don't use that parameter at all)

Web searches turned up only some very old problems with version 2.0 and 2.4. There is a similar question here: [Null Pointer Exception in WSDServiceFactory - Apache CXF libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428311/null-pointer-exception-in-wsdservicefactory-apache-cxf-libs) , but the answer was just to use an old version...

Could this be a configuration problem? Do I need any configuration files in my project?

Comment: I found similar problem check the possible solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578380/error-after-upgrading-camel-cxf-to-2-15-2-class-cast-exception/42023591#42023591

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was apparently caused by incompatible library versions. It seems that at least the WS client code generated by `wsdl2java` can run in Domino 9.0.1 without adding any jars from CXF (I had added some jars to the project).