# Error after upgrading camel-cxf to 2.15.2 . Class Cast exception

Tags: apache-camel

After upgrading to apache camel-cxf to 2.15.2 and cxf 3.0.4 I have the following problem when starting up my camel routes.

The route does a soap integration with a Payment Gateway.

Has any body found a workaround for this?

Please see stack trace below.

> Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException:
>   org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateProducerException: Failed to create
>   Producer for endpoint:
>   Endpoint[cxf://https://staging.payu.co.za/service/PayUAPI?dataFormat=PAYLOAD&portName=%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fsoap.api.controller.web.payjar.com%2F%7DEnterpriseAPISoapPort&serviceName=%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fsoap.api.controller.web.payjar.com%2F%7DEnterpriseAPISoapService&wsdlURL=https%3A%2F%2Fstaging.payu.co.za%2Fservice%2FPayUAPI%3Fwsdl].
>   Reason: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl to
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager   at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:349)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.java:66)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.java:43)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161)
>     ... 11 more
>
> ```
> Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateProducerException: Failed to create Producer for endpoint:
> ```
>
> Endpoint[cxf://https://staging.payu.co.za/service/PayUAPI?dataFormat=PAYLOAD&portName=%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fsoap.api.controller.web.payjar.com%2F%7DEnterpriseAPISoapPort&serviceName=%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fsoap.api.controller.web.payjar.com%2F%7DEnterpriseAPISoapService&wsdlURL=https%3A%2F%2Fstaging.payu.co.za%2Fservice%2FPayUAPI%3Fwsdl].
>   Reason: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl to
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.acquireProducer(ProducerCache.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.doStart(SendProcessor.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.doStart(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:1272)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.doStart(DefaultChannel.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doStart(MulticastProcessor.java:1122)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.startChildService(RouteService.java:340)
>     at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:182)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3090)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3020)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:2797)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:2653)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2467)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2463)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2486)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2463)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2432)
>     at
>   com.unijunction.ordercloud.common.bootstrap.CamelInstantiator.init(CamelInstantiator.java:58)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doLifecycleInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:114)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:103)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionInterceptor.java:53)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory.java:107)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:28)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.java:56)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.java:100)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
>     ... 27 more
>
> ```
> Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast
> ```
>
> org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl to
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager   at
>   org.apache.camel.component.cxf.WSDLServiceFactoryBean.getDefinition(WSDLServiceFactoryBean.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.cxf.WSDLServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(WSDLServiceFactoryBean.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:525)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:215)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:91)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint.createClient(CxfEndpoint.java:634)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.doStart(CxfProducer.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:2869)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doAddService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1097)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1058)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:405)
>     ... 104 more
>
> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl to
> ```
>
> org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager   at
>   java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3186)     at
>   org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.getBeanOfType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:322)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.getExtension(ExtensionManagerBus.java:216)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.cxf.WSDLServiceFactoryBean.getDefinition(WSDLServiceFactoryBean.java:64)
>     ... 117 more

Comment: When having ClassCastExceptions its sometimes because you have mutliple versions of Camel / CXF on the classpath by mistake. As you did an upgrade, then make sure its all on the same version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common problems found with camel and cfx:

- Duplicated versions of camel/cfx on the shaded jar files, because I found problems with cxf - 3.0.12 and 3.1.10.
- Problems on the camel TypeConverter.

Solution:

- Maven dependencies, apache cxf version 2.7.18 and apache camel version 2.17.2.

cxf-bundle

camel-core

camel-cxf

- Include this in the shaded maven pom,

  ```
              <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter</resource>
              </transformer>
  ```